# C# Code: Is this how ASP.NET AJAX scripts work?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, html

I am learning C# & ASP.NET to make a website. I am attempting to access a .aspx script through AJAX & just get some HTML back.

So I access the script http://www.mywebsite.com/test.aspx?i=199 & all it returns is:

```
<p>You queried: 199</p>
```

**Does ASP.NET allow me to pass CGI variables(*i=199*) or am I meant to use a different method?**

**Is this the correct way you are meant to use scripts in a ASP.NET websites:**

test.aspx:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="test.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.test" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<div id="testDiv" runat="server"></div>

<!-- Must I have the html, head & body elements or can I just return a div? -->
```

test.aspx.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class test : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int index = url.Split("i=").Last(); // this causes an error: split has some invalid arguments
            testDiv.InnerHtml = string.Format("<p>You Queried: {0}", index);
        }
    }
}
```

The way I use the script is to have a button on my home page that when click makes an AJAX request to test.aspx & gets back the p HTML element/text:

```
function getData( n )
{
     $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "test.aspx",
      data: "i="+n
      }).done(function( msg ) {
           $("textarea:first").html(msg) );
       });
}

<button onclick="getData(199)"/>
```

Comment: FYI, that's not a CGI variable. It's just a query string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't specific to asp.net.

You need to look at the [request object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.aspx), specifically the [Query String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.querystring.aspx) collection. These concepts are common to many web server side languages/frameworks. Through personal experience Ive used it in classic asp, asp.net and php.

To get the value from the query string:

```
string val = Request.QueryString["i"];
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You do not need html, head and body elements here. They are all automatically generated by `ASP.NET`
2. You can use `Request.QueryString("i")` . You do not need to manually parse the Url.
3. So far so good, but I do not understand `<button onclick="getData(199)"/>`

Where is this code written ? ASP.NET serverside controls `onclick` method would require C# implementation. IF you want to define client script, use `onclientclick`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.onclick.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can have the page return HTML, JSON or XML or just a string - It's up to you!
See discussion here for more info: http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2005/12/the_ajax_respon.html

The page receives the request and can use it's post or get variables.